# Automation Anywhere: How to get all the chrome windows

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

There can be more than one chrome windows open. Is there a way to get all of them to loop through? `Activate Window: "*- Google Chrome"` will only activate one of the many chrome windows.

**Use Case Scenario**

For attended bot where the users need to open several Chrome windows and work among them. They need to get data A from one website, and with data A, lookup additional data B, C, D and so on from other websites, compose some messages based on some templates with inserted data B, C, D and return the messages in one of the Chrome windows.

Comment: Is there any way to open the chrome windows 1 by 1, instead of having multiples open? I know this might hinder performance, but if the trade-off is accuracy, it's a choice I would gladly make any day.

Comment: No, I cannot change the way the users work, the users required multiple data from various websites. Speed is the no. 1 criteria, opening and closing windows is too slow, it'll be 10 seconds behind if no AA is used. The solution I used, which is donwvoted for unknown reason, is to use exsting loaded webpage if it exists, thereby avoiding unnecessary opeing of browser tab and loading new webpage, which takes time.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop when the window exists, get the window title and close the window with that window title.
Example:
[image: Example]

Comment: Good attempt, but I cannot close an open window.

Comment: I dont know your requirements, but maybe you could try to save the url for each window and then reopen them

Comment: Closing a window will loose the application states and ajax data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to make this on AA current version. The best choice is to make a script that returns the values of all the Windows and then loop through it.

Something like this

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works but it's not a pure AA solution, it requires running a script, which I need to learn.

Comment: What is want to achieve is not possible using pure AA as of now, using scripts is the only way to loop in open windows(Provided that 2 windows don't share exact titles)

Comment: Also the script for getting titles of open windows of any particular application is just a google search away

Comment: Using `tasklist` to get open windows titles takes too long time to execute in vbs. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score -1):

The solution I use is to get all the possible window titles and put them in a list, and loop through the list. Note that each of the tabs in Chrome could be a window title and need to be included in the list.

[image]

Comment: It'll be helpful for me to know the reason of the downvote so I may learn and improve on the solution. As of now, this solutoin is the best that I can come up with, even though it's not good enough. The best would be to loop through all open browser windows. The script to list running processes takes too long time and it won't list all chrome windows' titles. I welcome a solution that is better than what I'm using now.